# System of linear equations with infinite solution

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Assume that I have a $2\times2$ matrix with unknow values of $P_1$, $P_2$, $P_3$ and $P_4$:
$$x=\begin{bmatrix}P_1&P_2\\P_3&P_4\end{bmatrix}$$
However, we know the projections in each directions. So, we have:
$$P_1+P_2=a_1$$
$$P_3+P_4=a_2$$
$$P_1+P_3=a_3$$
$$P_2+P_4=a_4$$
($a_1$,$a_2$,$a_3$ and $a_4$are known values.)

This system of equations will have infinite solutions. I am wondering what kind of constraint I need to have as the prior knowledge that may help me to find a unique solution?
Thank you.

Comment: Observe that $a_1+a_2=a_3+a_4$. If this constraint is not verified, the system has no solution. Otherwise it has an infinity.

Comment: Add $\det x = m$. I tried and the system had one solution, provided that $a_1+a_2\ne 0$. Namely $\quad P_1=\dfrac{a_1^2+a_2 a_1-a_3 a_1-a_4 a_1+m}{a_1+a_2},P_2=\dfrac{a_1 a_3+a_1 a_4-m}{a_1+a_2},\\P_3=\dfrac{a_2^2+a_1 a_2-a_3 a_2-a_4 a_2-m}{a_1+a_2},P_4=\dfrac{a_2 a_3+a_2 a_4+m}{a_1+a_2}$